# Check snapshot to see if it has data or documents in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display a TableCalendar widget and display events if they exist in a firebase db.

I am using a StreamBuilder to get the events from the db.

Currently, the "events" collection does not exist so the snapshot should not have any data.

My problem is that the line where I am checking to see if there is data always passes as true. This is the line I am talking about:

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
```

How do I test for this so, in this case where there is not yet an "events" collection, I can bypass this code and just display the calendar widget?

Here is the code I am using:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
                .collection('events')
                .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
                .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              // Handle any errors
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Error fetching data: ${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              }
              debugPrint('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                  List<Events> eventsList = snapshot.data.docs
                      .map((e) => Events.fromJson(e))
                      .toList();
                  return _buildTableCalendar(eventsList);
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }
            },
          ),
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does snapshot.data print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be that even if there are no documents in the `events` collection, the QuerySnapshot still exists, but it is empty. In your code, `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.data != null` will always be true because the QuerySnapshot exists even if it is empty. Instead, you should check if snapshot.data.docs is not empty.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
    .collection('events')
    .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
    .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
    .snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    // Handle any errors
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error fetching data: ${snapshot.error}'),
      );
    }
    debugPrint('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      // Check if snapshot.data.docs is not empty
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        List<Events> eventsList = snapshot.data!.docs
            .map((e) => Events.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();
        return _buildTableCalendar(eventsList);
      } else {
        // If snapshot.data.docs is empty, do something like maybe build empty calendar
        return _buildTableCalendar([]);
      }
    }
  },
),
```